# Document recovery dialog in MSWord

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, comparison, file-recovery, file-comparison

There is [Autosaved] and [Original] files in the Document Recovery dialog, which lets me to open one or both files and then save them. The problem is that the files are very large and I cannot see what is the difference. Probably I do not want the latest. How can I see see the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Probably I do not want the latest.

The "Autosaved" document will be newer than the "Original" document.

---

#### How can I see see the difference?

> **Compare documents with the legal blackline option**
>
> The legal blackline option compares two documents and displays only
>   what changed between them. The documents that are being compared are
>   not changed. The legal blackline comparison is displayed by default in
>   a new third document.
>
> If you want to compare changes from a number of reviewers, do not
>   select this option. Choose Combine revisions from multiple authors
>   into a single document instead.
>
> 1. Open the documents that you want to compare.
> 2. On the Review tab, in the Compare group, click Compare.
>
>    [image: o14 ribbon]
> 3. Click Compare two versions of a document (legal blackline).
> 4. Under Original document, browse for the document that you want to use as the original document.
> 5. Under Revised document, browse for the other document that you want to compare.
> 6. Click More, and then select the settings for what you want to compare in the documents. Under Show changes, choose whether you want
>      to show character or word level changes.
>
>    If you do not want to display changes in a third document, choose
>      which document you want the changes to appear in.
>
>    Important:   Any options that you select under More will be the
>      default options for comparison the next time you compare documents.
> 7. Click OK.
> 8. If either version of the document has tracked changes, Microsoft Word displays a message box. Click Yes to accept the changes and
>      compare the documents.
> 9. Microsoft Office Word displays a new third document in which tracked changes in the original document are accepted, and changes in
>      the revised document are shown as tracked changes.
>
>    The source documents that are being compared are not changed.

Source [Compare documents with the legal blackline option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-documents-with-the-legal-blackline-option-dbfc7351-4022-43a2-a0c4-54d1898702a0)

Comment: um, My Doc Recovery clearly says that [Autosave] created at 23:00 whereas [Oritinal] at 16:30 on the same day. I probably need to revise my notion of `newer`. Secondly, I cannot find the `Tools Menu`. I have `Revision > Track Changes` but it lacks the `Compare Documents`

Comment: Apologies the link was for Mac Word 2011. I will update the answer immediately.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov Answer updated for Windows Word 2010